# Meaning of "within" in a certain context

Tags: meaning

What does the word *within* in the sentence below mean:

> Please log on to Application Web *within* 5 July 2018 to accept the offer:

If today is 1 July then does it tell the reader that they should accept the offer in only one day which is from 0 am to 12 pm 5 July, or they can accept the offer no later than 5 July?

Comment: It is badly phrased. "before" or "by" would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a deadline, so from now on until July 5th you need to accept.

It's not really idiomatic; a clearer way to phrase this would have been to say *by 5th July*. You would normally use *within* with a duration, such as *within five days*, whereas *by* is used with a specific point in time.

If you were only able to log in on July 5th it would have to be *on July 5th*, or perhaps *during July 5th*.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain their reasoning...?